# R: How to set the row names to the last column in read.table()

Tags: r, file-read

I usually use `dat = read.table(filename, row.names=1)` if the row names are in the first column. What is the corresponding call when the row names are in the last column of the file? I tried `dat = read.table(filename, row.names=ncol(dat))` but this did not work as expected, since `dat` variable does not exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to use `count.fields`

```
read.table('filename.csv', sep=",", 
       row.names = count.fields('filename.csv', sep=",")[1], header = TRUE)
#   col1 col2
#C    1    A
#F    2    B
#D    3    C
#G    4    D
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:2, col2 = LETTERS[1:4],
           col3 = c('C', 'F', 'D', 'G'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
write.csv(df1, 'filename.csv', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in `tibble` to do this `column_to_rownames`

```
dat <- read.table(filename)
dat <- tibble::column_to_rownames(dat, var = "target")
```

This provides the benefit of using the column name, the order of columns in your source is less relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just cut and paste the header row into the correct position at the top.  Then, speak with you data pipeline folks about why headers are appearing on the bottom of the file.  If you want an R solution to this, I can offer the following code.

I don't think there is a nice way to do this using `read.table` or `read.csv`.  These functions were designed with the header being on the top of the file.  You could try the following:

```
library(readr)

df <- NULL
cols <- list()
line <- 0L
input <- "start"
while (input != "") {
    line <- line + 1L
    input <- read_lines( file, skip = line - 1L, n_max = 1L )
    cols <- strsplit(input, " ")
    df <- rbind(df, cols)
}

# remove the last row, which is really just the header names
df <- head(df, -1)

# now take the very last line and assign the names
names(df) <- as.character(cols)
```